# compare and combine two Objects in java which produces as JSON

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

I have two objects of type `ClassA<List<List<String>>>` which retruns as a JSON from controller. I want to merge these two objects based on two properties(country and operator) if they are equal. Example JSON looks like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/controller3"method= RequestMethod.GET produces= MediaType.APPLIACTION_JSON_VALUE)
public ClassA<List<List<String>>> process(HttpServletRequest request) {
    ClassA<List<List<String>>> one = service.getvalues();
    ClassA<List<List<String>>> two = service.getvaluestwo();
    return merge(one, two);
}
```

JSON1 looks like

```
  "title": "Source",
  "dateRange": "23 August 2017 - 21 November 2017",
  "total": 336,
  "pageSize": 336,
  "pageNum": -1,
  "nextPageKey": "",
  "results": [
    [
      "India",
      "Idea",
      "30"
    ],
    "headers": [
        "Country",
        "Operator",
        "Count"
  ]
```

JSON2 looks like

```
  "title": "Source",
  "dateRange": "23 August 2017 - 21 November 2017",
  "total": 336,
  "pageSize": 336,
  "pageNum": -1,
  "nextPageKey": "",
  "results": [
    [
      "India",
      "Idea",
      "20"
    ],
    "headers": [
        "Country",
        "Operator",
        "Count"
  ]
```

I want the Resultant JSON would extracted from RestController from the type `ClassA<List<List<String>>>` would looks like

```
  "title": "Source",
  "dateRange": "23 August 2017 - 21 November 2017",
  "total": 336,
  "pageSize": 336,
  "pageNum": -1,
  "nextPageKey": "",
  "results": [
    [
      "India",
      "Idea",
      "30",
      "20",
      "50"
    ],
    "headers": [
        "Country",
        "Operator",
        "Count1",
        "Count2",
        "Total"
  ]
```

if there is no match then aggregate them as with zero count of each other.
Can you guys help me?

Comment: This doesn't look like a simple merge because it looks like you are adding some values, specifically when you have `"30"` in the first JSON object and `"20"` in the second JSON object, but you have `"50"` in the final object.  Have you considered implementing your own merge to get the logic you want?

Comment: the json are not in a valid format. do u mind updating that as well?